# "find_elements_by_xpath" can not get multiple item

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my test code for amazon.com result page("ipad" search)
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=ipad&ref=nb_sb_noss'
driver.get(url)
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-component-type="s-search-result"]')
print('items::', items)
```

output

> items:: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="16ca686bc84a7ff566fa2ee8ca4f5ec2", element="049c625c-d35f-4227-a8d3-085e1f379c1d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="16ca686bc84a7ff566fa2ee8ca4f5ec2", element="a520b080-806c-4f62-b3da-d37b7d1245db")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="16ca686bc84a7ff566fa2ee8ca4f5ec2", element="08bcb5c7-d34d-4157-b705-3ca2c65c060d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="16ca686bc84a7ff566fa2ee8ca4f5ec2", element="7ce94e98-70e9-4299-bda8-78060192a97e")>, ...SKIP

The code worked normally and could get multiple elements.

My Question:
This is my test code for ebay.com result page("ipad" search)
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url_ebay = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=ipad&rt=nc&_ipg=200&_pgn=2'
driver.get(url_ebay)
items = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "s-item__info") and contains(@class, "clearfix")]')
print('items::', items)
```

There are two class names (s-item__info,clearfix), so I use

```
"//div[contains(@class, "s-item__info") and contains(@class, "clearfix")]"
```

but output is single.

> items:: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="78784eaa3d666f344def61eb2c607bd3", element="61b055b4-6e69-4d1d-adf7-a4729d0b34b0")>

How to get all product elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: find_element**s**_by_xpath.
`find_element_by_xpath` return the first match, while
`find_elements_by_xpath` return all matches.